# irony server installation

Tags: gtags, irony-mode

Irony install server yeilds this error every time i try an installation. Clang requirements are all installed.

Can someone please help me out.

`-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "/tmp/build-irony-server-1.3.1/" -*-
Compilation started at Sat Jul  6 08:23:45`


`cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX\=/home/aviik/.emacs.d/irony/  /home/aviik/.emacs.d/elpa/irony-20190703.1732/server && cmake --build . --use-stderr --config Release --target install
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at /usr/lib/llvm-9/lib/cmake/clang/ClangTargets.cmake:581`

`(message):
  The imported target "clang_shared" references the file`

     `"/usr/lib/llvm-9/lib/libclang_shared.so.9"`

`but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:`

`* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.`

`* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.`

`* The installation package was faulty and contained`

`"/usr/lib/llvm-9/lib/cmake/clang/ClangTargets.cmake"`

`but not all the files it references.`

`Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/cmake/clang-9/ClangConfig.cmake:19 (include)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)`

`-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/build-irony-server-1.3.1/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".`

[CMakeOutput.log](https://pastebin.com/JT1TJFjc)

Comment: `/usr/lib/llvm-9/lib/libclang_shared.so.9` doesnt exist. Fix that.

Comment: i'm using clang-9 on Debian Stretch and installed all the files. this particular file doesnt exist but a file exists as a shortcut to libclang_shared.so.9